# Systemd service remains inactive due to code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Tags: boot, services, systemd, autostart

I have created a service on an Ubuntu 16.04 in order to run a c++ app after every boot.The c++ app runs among others  ping measurements ,and that's why I need to start it after the network is up and to have cap_net_raw=ep.  The service unit file I created and stored it under /etc/systemd/system/ is the following (app.service):

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
ExecStart=/home/app/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The script.sh contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo setcap cap_net_raw=ep /home/app/C++_APP  
cd /home/app
gnome-terminal -e "./C++_APP"
```

I have also given the following commands:

```
   chmod +x /home/app/script.sh    
   chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/app.service
   systemctl daemon-reload
   systemctl enable app.service
```

However when I reboot the os the c++ app is not run and when I give:

```
systemctl status app.service
```

I get the following message :

```
app.service    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/app.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-04-03 16:14:21 EEST; 2min 24s ago   Process: 2937 ExecStart=/home/user/script.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

When I run the script manually it works fine. Has anyone any idea of what I have done wrong?

Comment: Do you need to run the app with gnome-terminal (visually, in the foreground), or would it be sufficient to run it directly in the background?

Comment: Your question is a variation of this FAQ: [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645)

Comment: Probably I need to have the option to run it visually in the foreground for debugging reasons , but normally it would be sufficient to run it in the background. However the requirement I have is to use only the systemd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemd` is not the right tool to run desktop apps like `gnome-terminal` in the foreground. Your `systemd` config will be running the app as `root`, which I presume you intend.  It will be unaware an unable to run an app in a particular user's foreground session.

Update your script to not use `gnome-terminal` and just make the app executable and run it directly.

To debug, you can have it log to STDOUT or STDERR and use `journalctl -u app.service` to review the logs. Reviewing nearby lines in the full `journalctl` output may also be helpful.

Also see this related post about running apps via the CLI vs with systemd:

- [Difference between systemd and terminal starting program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339638/difference-between-systemd-and-terminal-starting-program/339645)

Comment: thanks for your help. That was the problem. I just have one remaining question. When my c++ app is running and give systemctl stop npt.service the command does not ends execution and the app is still running. Should I give an argument in execstop field that will kill the specific pid ?

Comment: If my answer my helpful and correct, please upvote and accept it. If you have a second question, please ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your service file:

```
[Service]
User=root
```

This worked for me!